# Does the Haste Spell give +1 BAB or only +1 attack roll?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, attack

So, the haste spells would give a character +1 extra attack and.....

+1 bonus on attack roll.

Could that be considered BAB or it is just an attack roll bonus?

Example: A level 5 Barbarian (+5 BAB), after being hasted, would have 6 BAB or +5 BAB and +1 bonus attack roll?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: For reference, compare [Divine Power](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/divinePower.htm) which explicitly states "base attack bonus."

Answer (score 12):

### The bonus is to attack roll only.

*Player's Handbook* p.239:

> A *hasted* creature gains a +1 bonus on attack rolls ...

It's attack roll.

Answer (score 7):

BAB is short for "Base Attack Bonus," and although it has the word "bonus" in it, it's best to consider the entire phrase as a name. Unless a spell or effect specifically uses all three words together, the bonus to attack does not increase BAB.